# Have withLatestFrom wait until all sources have produced one value

Tags: rxjs

I'm making use of the `withLatestFrom` operator in RxJS in the normal way:

```
var combined = source1.withLatestFrom(source2, source3);
```

...to actively collect the most recent emission from `source2` and `source3` and to emit all three value only when `source1` emits.

But I cannot guarantee that `source2` or `source3` will have produced values *before* `source1` produces a value. Instead I need to wait until all three sources produce at least one value each before letting `withLatestFrom` do its thing.

The contract needs to be: if `source1` emits then `combined` will **always** eventually emit when the other sources finally produce. If `source1` emits multiple times while waiting for the other sources we can use the latest value and discard the previous values. **Edit:** as a marble diagram:

```
--1------------2---- (source)
----a-----b--------- (other1)
------x-----y------- (other2)
------1ax------2by--


--1------------2---- (source)
------a---b--------- (other1)
--x---------y------- (other2)
------1ax------2by--


------1--------2---- (source)
----a-----b--------- (other1)
--x---------y------- (other2)
------1ax------2by--
```

I can make a custom operator for this, but I want to make sure I'm not missing an obvious way to do this using the vanilla operators. It feels almost like I want `combineLatest` for the initial emit and then to *switch* to `withLatestFrom` from then on but I haven't been able to figure out how to do that.

**Edit:** Full code example from final solution:

```
var Dispatcher = new Rx.Subject();
var source1 = Dispatcher.filter(x => x === 'foo');
var source2 = Dispatcher.filter(x => x === 'bar');
var source3 = Dispatcher.filter(x => x === 'baz');

var combined = source1.publish(function(s1) {
    return source2.publish(function(s2) {
        return source3.publish(function(s3) {
            var cL = s1.combineLatest(s2, s3).take(1).do(() => console.log('cL'));
            var wLF = s1.skip(1).withLatestFrom(s2, s3).do(() => console.log('wLF'));

            return Rx.Observable.merge(cL, wLF);
        });
    });
});

var sub1 = combined.subscribe(x => console.log('x', x));

// These can arrive in any order
// and we can get multiple values from any one.
Dispatcher.onNext('foo');
Dispatcher.onNext('bar');
Dispatcher.onNext('foo');
Dispatcher.onNext('baz');

// combineLatest triggers once we have all values.
// cL
// x ["foo", "bar", "baz"]

// withLatestFrom takes over from there.
Dispatcher.onNext('foo');
Dispatcher.onNext('bar');
Dispatcher.onNext('foo');
// wLF
// x ["foo", "bar", "baz"]
// wLF
// x ["foo", "bar", "baz"]
```

Comment: What's the use case? Are you looking for `zip`?

Comment: `zip` won't do because all three sources will produce at wildly different rates. Use-case is `source1` is usually a human interaction, like a click, and the other sources are fetching data from various sources -- ajax response, SSE stream, etc.

Comment: I see. `join` seems to be pretty close then: http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/join.html

Comment: did you try with using withLatestFrom only? According to the docs and the behaviour I'm observing the withLatestFrom method actually does wait for every source to produce. Your full set of requirements is met by only using withLatestFrom. Looking at it from another perspective: the publish-nesting is an interesting way to handle operator switching problems.

Comment: In my experience withLatestFrom does wait for every source to produce, but that means it skips any events which occurred before that state happened. I'm experiencing a similar issue to the OP, where S1 emits most or all of its values before S2 emits one; I want it to wait for S2 and then emit for each S1 value with that value, but it just skips all by the last S1 value.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think the answer is more or less as you described, let the first value be a `combineLatest`, then switch to `withLatestFrom`. My JS is hazy, but I think it would look something like this:

```
var selector = function(x,y,z) {};

var combined = Rx.Observable.concat(
    source1.combineLatest(source2, source3, selector).take(1),
    source1.withLatestFrom(source2, source3, selector)
);
```

You should probably use `publish` to avoid multiple subscriptions, so that would look like this:

```
var combined = source1.publish(function(s1)
{
    return source2.publish(function(s2)
    {
        return source3.publish(function(s3)
        {
            return Rx.Observable.concat(
                s1.combineLatest(s2, s3, selector).take(1),
                s1.withLatestFrom(s2, s3, selector)
            );
        });
    });
});
```

or using arrow functions...

```
var combined = source1.publish(s1 => source2.publish(s2 => source3.publish(s3 => 
    Rx.Observable.concat(
        s1.combineLatest(s2, s3, selector).take(1),
        s1.withLatestFrom(s2, s3, selector)
    )
)));
```

**EDIT**:

I see the problem with `concat`, the `withLatestFrom` isn't getting the values. I think the following would work:

```
var combined = source1.publish(s1 => source2.publish(s2 => source3.publish(s3 => 
    Rx.Observable.merge(
        s1.combineLatest(s2, s3, selector).take(1),
        s1.skip(1).withLatestFrom(s2, s3, selector)
    )
)));
```

...so take one value using `combineLatest`, then get the rest using `withLatestFrom`.

Comment: Thanks, I think you're on the right track here. Playing around it looks like `concat` lazily subscribes to the second observable so the `withLatestFrom` doesn't accumulate values until after the `combineLatest` completes. Using `merge` instead eagerly subscribes to both and does what I'm looking for. But I realize now there's a wrinkle in that if `source2` and `source3` produce before `source1` then _both_ `combineLatest` and `withLatestFrom` will be satisfied and both will emit at the same time. I could try to manually dedupe emissions within a very small window but that feels fragile.

Comment: did you give a try to my answer? That should take care of your cases. I mean the part with `flatMapLatest`

Comment: Is there an operator that can initially subscribe to multiple sequences but only emit values from one of them at a time by discarding or unsubscribing from the other? E.g., if we could unsubscribe to the `combineLatest` as soon as `withLatestFrom` produces, I think that would solve the wrinkle.

Comment: That's what `concat` does. I don't entirely understand why the `concat` doesn't work for you.

Comment: `combineLatest` is a superset of `withLatestFrom`. So you don't want to merge them, you want to `concat` them.

Comment: Sorry, to answer your question `amb` subscribes to multiple sequences, but only emits values from the first sequence to emit a value. See http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/amb.html

Comment: Sorry, I didn't explain that well. With `concat` the `combineLatest().take(1)` works as intended but the `withLatestFrom` is not collecting values _during that time_. So once the `combineLatest` completes the `withLatestFrom` then _starts_ listening from scratch.

Comment: I understand. I think that's what you want. Anything that `withLatestFrom` would emit, `combineLatest` would as well. It's a superset. In any event, if you don't trust that, you could use `amb` as follows as the first part of the `concat`: `Rx.Observable.amb(s1.combineLatest(s2, s3, selector), s1.withLatestFrom(s2, s3, selector)).take(1)`

Comment: I'm thinking over your `amb` suggestion now. Here's a jsbin of what I'm trying to accomplish: http://jsbin.com/dekeqoteji/2/edit?js,console

Comment: Subtle. Took me a second to wrap my head around it. Thank you very much! That ended up being a lot simpler than I thought. I was definitely overthinking the problem.

Comment: Hey guys! Great answer thanks. But I'm struggling to understand why everything was wrapped in the publish() operator and what is the actual argument of the publish() method? I cant seem to find any good documentation online regarding publish() argument.

Comment: I found [this](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/publish) though it doesn't explain much.

Comment: As the answer states, it solves the multiple subscription problem. If you reference an observable more than once, you get multiple subscriptions to that observable, which can often have adverse effects. The solution is to put the multi-referenced observable in a publish, which consolidates into one subscription.

Answer (score 7):

I wasn't quite satisfied with the accepted answer, so I ended up finding another solution. Many ways to skin a cat!

My use-case involves just two streams - a "requests" stream and a "tokens" stream. I want requests to fire as soon as they are received, using the whatever the latest token is. If there is no token yet, then it should wait until the first token appears, and then fire off all the pending requests.

I wasn't quite satisfied with the accepted answer, so I ended up finding another solution. Essentially I split the request stream into two parts - before and after first token arrives. I buffer the first part, and then re-release everything in one go once I know that the token stream is non-empty.

```js
const first = token$.first()

Rx.Observable.merge(
  request$.buffer(first).mergeAll(),
  request$.skipUntil(first)
)
  .withLatestFrom(token$)
```

See it live here: https://rxviz.com/v/VOK2GEoX

**For RxJs 7:**

```js
const first = token$.first()

merge(
  request$.pipe(
    buffer(first),
    mergeAll()
  ),
  request$.pipe(
    skipUntil(first)
  )
).pipe(
  withLatestFrom(token$)
)
```

Comment: Clever approach. The `buffer` semantics differ from the accepted answer which does not buffer and could pose a problem if the left-hand produces for a significant period of time before the right-hand produces. But setting that aside, this is a nice, lightweight solution.

Comment: Can this be modified to work for multiple stream? I can't get my head around how it would work

Answer (score 2):

I had similar requirements but for just 2 observables.
I ended up using switchMap+first:

```
observable1
 .switchMap(() => observable2.first(), (a, b) => [a, b])
 .subscribe(([a, b]) => {...}));
```

So it:

- waits until both observables emit some value
- pulls the value from second observable only if the first one has changed (unlike combineLatest)
- doesn't hang subscribed on second observable (because of .first())

In my case, second observable is a ReplaySubject. I'm not sure if it will work with other observable types.

I think that:

- flatMap would probably work too
- it might be possible to extend this approach to handle more than 2 observables

I was surprised that `withLatestFrom` will not wait on second observable.

Comment: This seems to be a great answer, if you change the resultsSelector to an inner map, since the results selector is now deprecated. It seems to do what the answer by cjol does, but more simple.

Comment: If you wish to buffer multiple values from `source` before `others`, this will not work.

Answer (score 2):

In my mind, the most elegant way to achieve the different behavior of an existing RxJS operator is to wrap it into a custom operator. So that from the outside it looks just like any regular operator and doesn't require you to restructure your code each time you need this behavior.

Here is how you can create your own operator which behaves just like `withLatestFrom`, except that at the very beginning it will emit as soon as the first value of the target observable is emitted (unlike standard `withLatestFrom`, which will ignore the first emission of the source if the target hasn't yet emitted once). Let's call it `delayedWithLatestFrom`.

Note that it's written in TypeScript, but you can easily transform it to plain JS. Also, it's a simple version that supports **only one target observable** and no `selector` function - you can extend it as needed from here.

```js
export function delayedWithLatestFrom<T, N>(
  target$: Observable<N>
): OperatorFunction<T, [T, N]> {
  // special value to avoid accidental match with values that could originate from target$
  const uniqueSymbol = Symbol('withLatestFromIgnore');

  return pipe(
    // emit as soon target observable emits the first value
    combineLatestWith<T, [N]>(target$.pipe(first())),
    // skip the first emission because it's handled above, and then continue like a normal `withLatestFrom` operator
    withLatestFrom(target$.pipe(skip(1), startWith(uniqueSymbol))),
    map(([[rest, combineLatestValue], withLatestValue]) => {
      // take combineLatestValue for the first time, and then always take withLatestValue
      const appendedValue =
        withLatestValue === uniqueSymbol ? combineLatestValue : withLatestValue;

      return [rest, appendedValue];
    })
  );
}

// SAMPLE USAGE
source$.pipe(
  delayedWithLatestFrom(target$)
).subscribe(console.log);
```

So if you compare it with the [original marble diagram for `withLatestFrom`](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/withLatestFrom), it will differ only in one fact: while `withLatestFrom` ignores the first emissions and produces `b1` as the first value, the `delayedWithlatestFrom` operator will emit one more value `a1` at the beginning, as soon as the second observable emits `1`.

a) Standard `withLatestFrom`:
[image: marble diagram of withLatestFrom]

b) Custom `delayedWithLatestFrom`:
[image: marble diagram of delayedWithLatestFrom]

Answer (score 1):

Use `combineLatest` and `filter` to remove tuples before first full set is found then set a variable to stop filtering. The variable can be within the scope of a wrapping `defer` to do things properly (support resubscription). Here it is in java (but the same operators exist in RxJs):

```
Observable.defer(
    boolean emittedOne = false;
    return Observable.combineLatest(s1, s2, s3, selector)
        .filter(x -> {
            if (emittedOne) 
               return true;
            else {
               if (hasAll(x)) {
                   emittedOne = true;
                   return true;
               } else 
                   return false; 
            }
        });
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I wanted a version where tokens are fetched regularly - and where I want to retry the main data `post` on (network) failure.  I found shareReplay to be the key.  The first mergeWith creates a "muted" stream, which causes the first token to be fetched immediately, not when the first `action` arrives. In the unlikely event that the first token will still not be available in time, the logic also has a `startWith` with an invalid value. This causes the retry logic to pause and try again. (`Some`/`map` is just a Maybe-monad):

```js
Some(fetchToken$.pipe(shareReplay({refCount: false, bufferSize: 1})))
    .map(fetchToken$ =>
        actions$.pipe(
            // This line is just for starting the loadToken loop immediately, not waiting until first write arrives.
            mergeWith(fetchToken$.pipe(map(() => true), catchError(() => of(false)), tap(x => loggers.info(`New token received, success: ${x}`)), mergeMap(() => of()))),
            concatMap(action =>
                of(action).pipe(
                    withLatestFrom(fetchToken$.pipe(startWith(""))),
                    mergeMap(([x, token]) => (!token ? throwError(() => "Token not ready") : of([x, token] as const))),
                    mergeMap(([{sessionId, visitId, events, eventIds}, token]) => writer(sessionId, visitId, events, token).pipe(map(() => <ISessionEventIdPair>{sessionId, eventIds}))),
                    retryWhen(errors =>
                        errors.pipe(
                            tap(err => loggers.warn(`Error writing data to WG; ${err?.message || err}`)),
                            mergeMap((_error: any, attemptIdx) => (attemptIdx >= retryPolicy.retryCount ? throwError(() => Error("It's enough now, already")) : of(attemptIdx))), // error?.response?.status  (int, response code) error.code === "ENOTFOUND" / isAxiosError: true / response === undefined
                            delayWhen(attempt => timer(attempt < 2 ? retryPolicy.shortRetry : retryPolicy.longRetry, scheduler))
                        )
                    )
                )
            ),
        )
    )
```

Thanks to everyone on this question-page for good inputs.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the answer from @cjol

Here's a RxJs 7 implementation of a `waitFor` operator that will buffer the source stream until all input observables have emitted values, then emit all buffered events on the source stream. Any subsequent events on the source stream are emitted immediately.

```js
// Copied from the definition of withLatestFrom() operator.
export function waitFor<T, O extends unknown[]>(
  inputs: [...ObservableInputTuple<O>]
): OperatorFunction<T, [T, ...O]>;

/**
 * Buffers the source until every observable in "from" have emitted a value. Then
 * emit all buffered source values with the latest values of the "from" array.
 * Any source events are emitted immediately after that.
 * @param from Array of observables to wait for.
 * @returns Observable that emits an array that concatenates the source and the observables to wait.
 */
export function waitFor(
  from: Observable<unknown>[]
): (source$: Observable<unknown>) => Observable<unknown> {
  const combined$ = combineLatest(from);
  // This served as a conditional that switched on and off the streams that
  // wait for the the other observables, or emits the source right away because
  // the other observables have emitted.
  const firstCombined$ = combined$.pipe(first());

  return function (source$: Observable<unknown>): Observable<unknown> {
    return merge(
      // This stream will buffer the source until the other observables have all emitted.
      source$.pipe(
        takeUntil(firstCombined$), // without this it continues to buffer new values forever
        buffer(firstCombined$),
        mergeAll()
      ),
      // This stream emits the source straight away and will take over when the other
      // observables have emitted.
      source$.pipe(skipUntil(firstCombined$))
    ).pipe(
      withLatestFrom(combined$),
      // Flatten it to behave like withLatestFrom() operator.
      map(([source, combined]) => [source, ...combined])
    );
  };
}
```

Comment: This is useful for NgRx effects where an effect needs to wait for other states in the store.

Answer (score 0):

All of the above solutions are not really on the point, therefore I made my own. Hope it helps someone out.

````js
import {
  combineLatest,
  take,
  map,
  ObservableInputTuple,
  OperatorFunction,
  pipe,
  switchMap
} from 'rxjs';

/**
 * ### Description
 * Works similar to {@link withLatestFrom} with the main difference that it awaits the observables.
 * When all observables can emit at least one value, then takes the latest state of all observables and proceeds execution of the pipe.
 * Will execute this pipe only once and will only retrigger pipe execution if source observable emits a new value.
 * 
 * ### Example
 * ```ts
 * import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';
 * import { awaitLatestFrom } from './await-latest-from.ts';
 * 
 * const myNumber$ = new BehaviorSubject<number>(1);
 * const myString$ = new BehaviorSubject<string>("Some text.");
 * const myBoolean$ = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(true);
 *
 * myNumber$.pipe(
 *  awaitLatestFrom([myString$, myBoolean$])
 * ).subscribe(([myNumber, myString, myBoolean]) => {});
 * ```
 * ### Additional
 * @param observables - the observables of which the latest value will be taken when all of them have a value.
 * @returns a tuple which contains the source value as well as the values of the observables which are passed as input.
 */
export function awaitLatestFrom<T, O extends unknown[]>(
  observables: [...ObservableInputTuple<O>]
): OperatorFunction<T, [T, ...O]> {
  return pipe(
    switchMap((sourceValue) =>
      combineLatest(observables).pipe(
        take(1),
        map((values) => [sourceValue, ...values] as unknown as [T, ...O])
      )
    )
  );
}
````

Answer (score -3):

Actually `withLatestFrom` already

- waits for every source
- emits only when source1 emits
- remembers only the last source1-message while the other sources are yet to start

```js
// when source 1 emits the others have emitted already
var source1 = Rx.Observable.interval(500).take(7)
var source2 = Rx.Observable.interval(100, 300).take(10)
var source3 = Rx.Observable.interval(200).take(10)

var selector = (a,b,c) => [a,b,c]
source1
  .withLatestFrom(source2, source3, selector)
  .subscribe()
```

vs

```
// source1 emits first, withLatestFrom discards 1 value from source1
var source1 = Rx.Observable.interval(500).take(7)
var source2 = Rx.Observable.interval(1000, 300).take(10)
var source3 = Rx.Observable.interval(2000).take(10)

var selector = (a,b,c) => [a,b,c]
source1
  .withLatestFrom(source2, source3, selector)
  .subscribe()
```

Comment: The accepted answer is correct. `withLatestFrom` only emits when `source` emits which is not what I was asking for. The OP would have been much more clear with marble diagrams.

Comment: Edited OP to add marble diagrams.

Comment: No. The added marbles would be produced exactly the way you want with only withLatestFrom. Until all sources have a value those two operators behave the same.

Comment: They do not behave the same. wLF emits in response to `source` only, and then not until after `other1` and `other2` have produced values. This may be more clear to you if you manually populate each source like in OP. `Dispatcher.onNext('foo'); Dispatcher.onNext('bar'); Dispatcher.onNext('baz')` will **not** emit when using wLF until another 'foo' arrives.